# Generate major page faults

Tags: kernel, memory, virtual-memory

Is it possible to generate major page faults in the linux kernel at will? Can a program be written such that it is guaranteed to cause a major page fault on it's execution.

Comment: Hmmm....what problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm trying to tweak the page replacement algorithm in Linux and needed a way to test it effectively. The aim is to write a program that can generate page faults as a way to test the modifications made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce major page faults you need to force reads from disk. The following code maps the file given on the command-line, telling the kernel it doesn't need it; if the file is large enough (pick a large file in `/usr/bin`), you'll always get major page faults:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  struct stat stats;
  fstat(fd, &stats);
  posix_fadvise(fd, 0, stats.st_size, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
  char * map = (char *) mmap(NULL, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Failed to mmap");
    return 1;
  }
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < stats.st_size; i++) {
    result += map[i];
  }
  munmap(map, stats.st_size);
  return result;
}
```

There isn't much in the way of error handling, this is just to demonstrate the idea. On my system,

```
gcc majorfault.c -o majorfault && /usr/bin/time -v ./majorfault /usr/bin/git-annex
```

always produces 154 major page faults.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Stephen. I tried this out on Ubuntu and am only seeing a single major page fault. I'm running it with a 2GB file. Please could you share any insights into why this maybe happening.

Comment: I was able to generate more page faults by accessing every 100th page. Thanks again for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This C program causes the memory pressure graph on my Mac to spike PDQ:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        char* p = malloc(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
            p[i * 1024 * 1024] = 0;     /* touch the pages */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The inner loop is important. If you don't touch at least some of the memory pages you allocate, the memory management subsystem is smart enough to realize that you're just asking for memory you never use. That may well be an OS X specific implementation detail, however.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, Warren; I'm trying this on Ubuntu and it segfaults on the fourth malloc. Any insights into why this maybe happening?

Comment: Another concern I have is that on inspecting the page faults on the system caused by this process using stap, I find all of them to be minor faults:

6840611:5592:55790008:w:minor:2

6840614:5592:55791008:w:minor:1

6840618:5592:55792008:w:minor:2

6840621:5592:55793008:w:minor:2

Comment: My code isn't checking the return value of `malloc()`. It's almost certainly segfaulting on a null pointer dereference in the inner loop. You'll want to refine it a bit if your goal is to make a specific system start swapping pages to disk *without* killing the test program explicitly or angering the [Linux OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). Specifically, you probably want to allocate in chunks much smaller than 1 GiB. I just did that to make it show the effect quickly.

Comment: Thanks so much, Warren. This really helped me. +1 for helping me understand why it's segfaulting.