# Weird major page fault number when reading sequentially / randomly in mmap region

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, virtual-memory, mmap

I'm following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188215/365462), trying to generate some major page faults with `mmap`:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  struct stat stats;
  fstat(fd, &stats);
  posix_fadvise(fd, 0, stats.st_size, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
  char * map = (char *) mmap(NULL, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Failed to mmap");
    return 1;
  }
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < stats.st_size; i++) {
    result += map[i];
  }
  munmap(map, stats.st_size);
  return result;
}
```

I tried to map a `1.6G` file then read but only `1` major page fault occurred.

```
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 1
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 38139
```

When I read data randomly by

```c
// hopefully this won't trigger extra page faults
unsigned int idx = 0;
for (i = 0; i < stats.st_size; i++) {
  result += map[idx % stats.st_size];
  idx += i;
}
```

the page faults surged to `16415`

```
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 16415
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 37665
```

Is there something like prefetching in kernel to preload `mmap` data? How can I tell this by `/usr/bin/time` or `perf`?

I'm using `gcc 6.5.0` and `Ubuntu 18.04` with `4.15.0-54-generic`.

Comment: What's in your 1.6GB file? Does it have holes in it? (like, does `du` on the file report 1.6GB or much less than that?) How are you reading on the first case, producing only 1 major page fault?

Comment: @filbranden I just randomly picked a large file, hoping to generate numerous  major page faults. The file happened to be `cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run`, the installer for CUDA 9.1. `du` reported exactly 1.6GB. I used the code provided in the link. I'll edit the question to copy it here. By the way, what does `have holes in it` mean?

Comment: There's this thing called "sparse" files, where you have blocks of all zeroes that are not taking space in disk, clearly not the case here... I think you might be up to something with your comment on readahead, there might be something there.

Comment: Though, one thing you want to check is how this behaves if you clear the page cache in between runs. `echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as root. Do you get major page faults then? Do you see different behavior depending on linear vs random reads?

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help here. It is the same result as before. "Prefetching" is just my personal guess and I don't have any confidence about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the kernel does readahead by default (what you called prefetching), see https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/filemap.c?h=v5.5#n2476

You can disable readahead on this memory region by calling `posix_madvise()` after `mmap()` with the `POSIX_MADV_RANDOM` advice.